# How can I set the default value for reading a directory name?

Tags: interactive, directories

I have a folder hardcoded in variable:

```
(defvar folder-start-mine "/path/to/start/folder/")
```

Then I want to interactively define new non-existing subfolder name:

```
(defun my-new-defun (sel-subdir)  
     (interactive "GNew folder: " folder-start-mine)
     (mkdir sel-subdir)
     ... do some stuff with sel-subdir ...
)
```

The file navigator in minibuffer starts in home folder and I want it to start in folder-start-mine.

Comment: Do you intend for `folder-start-mine` to be the default value for `sel-subdir`, or do you want the value of `sel-subdir` to be a directory located inside/relative to `folder-start-mine`? You mention "It starts in the home folder", but I don't know what you're referring to?

Comment: The file navigator in minibuffer starts in `~/`. I want it to start in `/path/to/start/folder/`.
I want for `sel-subdir` to be a path to the new subfolder (this works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in support for prompting a user for a directory name, via the `G` flag as you have used, does not support setting the default directory. You can do this explicitly with a lisp expression instead of the usual interactive codes.

```
(defvar folder-start-mine "/path/to/start/folder/")

(defun my-new-defun (sel-subdir)  
  (interactive
   (list (read-directory-name "New Folder: " folder-start-mine)))
  (mkdir sel-subdir))
```

This will prompt the user for a directory name, starting from the value of `folder-start-mine`, and then use that as the value of the variable `sel-subdir`.